# Redirect specific subdomain pages to domain pages with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I hope this is the right forum for this question. If not my apologies. I am migrating a blog from blogger to wordpress. The blogger site used to have a sub domain of `subdomain.mydomain.com` . I have imported my blog over to word press on a private host on `mydomain.com` .

I would like to redirect

```
 subdomain.mydomain.com/post1
```

to

```
mydomain.com/post1.
```

I need to repeat this for multiple posts. The `/post1` part can be the same for each url, so `subdomain.mydomain.com` may only need to be rewritten to `mydomain.com`

What would be the correct entry in the .htaccess file to do this? Also, how long does it take to take effect? 
Can I clear my cache and then instantly see the results of the redirect if I visit the sub domain url?

Answer (score 0):

I found a non-programmatic way to solve this issue. This is what worked for me. In cpanel I pointed my subdomain to the directory of my main domain. This was done in the subdomain settings.

The second part was to go into the redirect settings in cpanel. I was able to choose the subdomain from the drop down, add the rest of the url after the subdomain in the next box, and then put in the link to redirect in the next box. I did this for each link that needed to be redirected.